# Asterisk call recording in single file for both channels

Tags: asterisk, telephony, telecommunication, asteriskami, asterisk-java

Currently asterisk is recording call in two separate wav files for both in and out channels and then merging them into one file. This merging is taking some time so we want to eliminate it.

Is there any way in which Asterisk by default create only 1 recording file for both the channels during call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk MixMonitor command in CURRENT versions of asterisk(11+) do save in single file.

Monitor command still save in two different files for script use.

Comment: If you're using one touch recording, then set: DYNAMIC_FEATURES=automixmon

Comment: But MixMonitor mixed both channels to single mono channel. If you want stereo file you need to join the files yourself.